# No answer_id for Comment on answer inbox_item

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

According to the [API documentation on inbox_item](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item), inbox items corresponding to a comment on an answer to a question should have an `answer_id` field identifying the answer that the comment was on, but that seems to be missing, and `answer_id` only seems to exist for inbox items about answer to questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest deploy should fix this bug.

Comments should have a `question_id` or `answer_id` as appropriate when returned by any of the inbox methods.